# Detect user device with blazor server

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

Is there a way to detect the device the user is using with blazor server on .net 7? or at least know what resolution they're using so i can check if it's portrait of landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

The only way the server can directly know anything about the client machine or browser is if that information is sent.  Do not depend on this happening.

If you really want to get real dimensions, there are many ways to do this in Javascript.  So you want to look up Javascript Interop in Blazor.

But if you need to know the dimensions of the screen, except in very special cases, you're probably doing things wrongly.  CSS rules include media queries, generally based on width.  CSS also includes unit measurements like vh and vw, which represent a proportion of the width or height of the screen.

***As a web developer, you will learn that fighting against the protocol of the day is likely to end up with you in tears-- because you make a solution that works on your own phone, and then someone with an Apple device, or an older device, or an uncommon browser, tries to use your site.  Then you discover that your "production" site is garbage.***

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to make a separate nav bar for mobile so i thought i can at least detect the resolution of the browser

Comment: In what way will the mobile version need to be different?  What phone-specific features do you need to implement?  (I'm not being argumentative, I actually have some experience with this stuff)

Comment: we have an app bar and we want to make it a sidebar on mobile, also i don't have any experience on the front end side other than the basic html / css and it's mostly my friend who's working on that side